# found this mint like plant in my back yard, help?

Tags: identification

This mint like plant is growing up against a stone wall. The stem is square and the leaves are opposite. There are small flower buds at every section of leaves, white in color. Very minimal mint smell, more musty. The leaves are variegated with a grey spot in the middle. Idk how to put pics on so plz help.

Comment: Picture? Is it a crosnes?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post is how you use photos

Comment: If you cut a stem what would the cross section look like?  Round?  Square? Triangular?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like one of the Lamiums, commonly known as deadnettle - they have square stems, and when the stems are long, flowers at the nodes. They can have plain green foliage, but more usually, there's a degree of variegation, whether that's just a stripe down the middle, or much broader variegation,including solid areas of white in the centre, or yellow, cream or white variegation. Example image below, but it would be useful to see a photograph of your particular plant

http://plants.echters.com/12130005/Plant/8559/White_Spotted_Dead_Nettle